# ¿Como acceder a la API REST de OCS Inventory?

Tags: linux, api, rest, debian, apache2

les platico mi problema, he instalado OCS Inventroy con éxito en un servidor virtual con Debian 11 recomendado por el mismo desarrollador, he conectado un agente OCS con éxito al servidor de prueba desde la máquina virtual, pero ahora tengo un detalle, este servicio de inventario permite usar una *API REST* el cual para uso leyendo en su documentación me dice que cambie unos accesos del servicio de apache, pero soy nuevo en este ambiente linux y no se que modificar exactamente para obtener los datos desde la *API REST*, dejo el link de la parte exacta que les comento:

[Docs » 11.Rest API » Authentification](https://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/11.Rest-API/Authentification/)

Dice que después de esto intente acceder a la lista de dispositivos con el siguiente link:

> http://myocsserver/ocsapi/v1/my/routes

Pero como no he logrado averiguar como quitar o agregar restricciones del apache me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que debo realizar para poder acceder a esta *API REST*?

Answer (score 0):

Lograste acceder a la data?

Modificaste el archivo
/etc/apache2/conf-availabe/zz-ocsinventory-restapi.conf
o el archivo
/etc/apache2/conf-available/zz-ocsinventory-restapi.conf

```
PerlOptions +Parent

<Perl>
  $ENV{PLACK_ENV} = 'production';
  $ENV{MOJO_HOME} = '/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2';
  $ENV{MOJO_MODE} = 'deployment';
  $ENV{OCS_DB_HOST} = 'localhost';
  $ENV{OCS_DB_PORT} = '3306';
  $ENV{OCS_DB_LOCAL} = 'ocsweb';
  $ENV{OCS_DB_USER} = 'ocs';
  $ENV{OCS_DB_PWD} = 'ocs';
</Perl>

<Location /ocsapi>
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
  PerlSetVar psgi_app '/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Api/Ocsinventory/Restapi/Loader.pm'
</Location>
```

Fuente: https://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/11.Rest-API/Configuration/

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).